# Download development releases of modules with Drush Make

Tags: drush

How do I get a development release of a module in the .make file of my installation profile?

I am writing this now to get the development release of better_exposed_filters.

```
projects[better_exposed_filters][version] = "3.0-beta3+31-dev"
```

When I run the .make file I get the following message:

> Could not locate better_exposed_filters version 7.x-3.0-beta3+31-dev, will try to download latest recommended or supported release.

Answer (score 2):

I tried generating a Drush make file with http://drushmake.me/, and the generated file contained the following lines.

```
projects[jquery_ui][version] = 1.x-dev
projects[jquery_ui][type] = "module"
projects[libraries][version] = 2.1
projects[libraries][type] = "module"
projects[xmlsitemap][version] = 2.0-rc2
projects[xmlsitemap][type] = "module"
```

I think that in your case you should use the following lines.

```
projects[better_exposed_filters][version] = 3.x-dev
projects[better_exposed_filters][type] = "module"
```

That would select the development snapshot for 3.x; in the case you want to select the 7.x-3.0-beta3 version, then you should use the following lines.

```
projects[better_exposed_filters][version] = 3.0-beta3
projects[better_exposed_filters][type] = "module"
```

The make file needs to contain the following line, which select Drupal 7 as Drupal version to use. This alters the version used for the modules; for example, the following line used with the latter lines I shown, would pick-up version 7.3.0-beta3 of the Better Exposed Filters module.

```
projects[drupal][version] = 7
```

Comment: Is it possible to target a specific snapshot, instead of just always the latest dev version? E.g. I found that 3.11+11-dev does not work. But maybe there is another syntax?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a specific dev version, you need to specify the Git commit ID on the branch you're looking for:

```
; Schema.org
projects[schemaorg][type] = module
projects[schemaorg][download][type] = git
projects[schemaorg][download][revision] = f860c7cc49e95d8420980d0dadd706172cc7955d
projects[schemaorg][download][branch] = 7.x-1.x
```

You can find the commit ID you need by doing the following:

1. Surf to the project page.
2. Click on *Browse code repository*.
3. In the Branch section, click on the branch you want.
4. From the "X.Y-betaZ+A-dev" string, find the Ath commit after the X.Y-betaZ release, and click on it.
5. You'll find the ID in the *commit* row and in your URL address bar.